# Android-NDK building using the Bambuser source

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am trying to use the FFmpeg source provided by the Bambuser.

However, I am fail to build the files

I get the following error:

> **arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
>   C compiler test failed.**

I have already set the NDK path to /home/android-ndk but still get this error

And I am using Android-NDK-r5b

can anyone help? THX

Here is my build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$NDK" = "" ]; then
    echo NDK variable not set, assuming ${HOME}/android-ndk
    export NDK=${HOME}/android-ndk
fi

SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-3/arch-arm
# Expand the prebuilt/* path into the correct one
TOOLCHAIN=`echo $NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows`
export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH

rm -rf build/ffmpeg
mkdir -p build/ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg

# Don't build any neon version for now
for version in armv5te armv7a; do

    DEST=../build/ffmpeg
    FLAGS="--target-os=linux --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --sysroot=$SYSROOT"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --soname-prefix=/data/data/com.streaming.realive/lib/"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --enable-shared --disable-symver"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --enable-small --optimization-flags=-O2"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --enable-encoder=mpeg4 --enable-decoder=mpeg4"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --enable-encoder=mpeg2video --enable-encoder=nellymoser"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --enable-protocol=rtp --enable-protocol=rtmp"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --enable-protocol=http --enable-protocol=tcp --enable-protocol=udp"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --enable-protocol=file"

    case "$version" in
        neon)
            EXTRA_CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon"
            EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
            # Runtime choosing neon vs non-neon requires
            # renamed files
            ABI="armeabi-v7a"
            ;;
        armv7a)
            EXTRA_CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp"
            EXTRA_LDFLAGS=""
            ABI="armeabi-v7a"
            ;;
        *)
            EXTRA_CFLAGS=""
            EXTRA_LDFLAGS=""
            ABI="armeabi"
            ;;
    esac
    DEST="$DEST/$ABI"
    FLAGS="$FLAGS --prefix=$DEST"

    mkdir -p $DEST
    echo $FLAGS --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" > $DEST/info.txt
    ./configure $FLAGS --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" | tee $DEST/configuration.txt
    [ $PIPESTATUS == 0 ] || exit 1
    make clean
    make -j4 || exit 1
    make install || exit 1

done
```

Answer (score 2):

**First** which platform u use?
I suggest Ubuntu.

**Second** make sure NDK path is correct.

**Third**     `FLAGS="$FLAGS --soname-prefix=/data/data/com.streaming.realive/lib/"`

maybe you need to create the relative folder in your computer

Comment: 1. I am using windows platform and using the Cygwin to run the command 2. I am sure my NDK path is correct /.\ 
3. I think this line is to rename the native function name so that we can call the function in the code isn't it?

Comment: I suggest in Ubuntu because i never build in windows sucessfully. and also not every build method is work for me.http://www.roman10.net/?p=389&cpage=2#comment-1103 This one work fine for me.You may have a try

Comment: and sorry i forget it..haha i have solve this problem once in windows.The method is you need to add a temp folder in windows with a new configure in build file >> $export TMPDIR=e:/temp

Comment: hey m getting same error. can u help? i dunno what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First check your `configure.log` file in the `ffmpeg` directory. In that the last few lines indicates the exact error you face. If you post that error, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows Operating System then, try to add your toolchain path (used in `build.sh`) to the `PATH` environmental variable (from `My Computer`'s properties).

For Example:

```
C:\android-ndk-r7\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\bin
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

here my config.log I also get the same issue when using bambuser script. I using ubuntu

```
type mktemp
mktemp is /bin/mktemp
WARNING: Unknown C compiler arm-linux-androideabi-gcc, unable to select optimal CFLAGS
check_ld
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.ItYaeeJM.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.ItYaeeJM.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -c -o /tmp/ffconf.woaTRE0T.o /tmp/ffconf.ItYaeeJM.c
./configure: 572: ./configure: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: not found
C compiler test failed.
```